# Cannot post membership/login/submit

Tags: node.js

I have some code to create an account and have a login page and say true or false if you entered the correct details but instead it says 'Cannot post /membership/login/submit'.

my main.js code (the html files are basic and the forms are just standard  tags with an action and a method, tell me if you want these)

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var httpuse = require('http');
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var users = require(__dirname + '/local_js/users.js');
var public = __dirname + "/www/";
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var needle = require('needle');
const saltRounds = 10;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

function rand(n) {
    Math.floor(Math.random() * (n+1));
}

function getToken(hashedpass, user) {
    return hashedpass+"_._"+user;
}

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(public + 'index.html');
});

app.get('/membership/create/form', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(public + 'user/create.html');
});

app.post('/membership/create/submit', function(req, res){
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(errdd, db) {
        if (errdd) throw errdd;
        var dbo = db.db("boaichat");

        bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
            if (err) {throw err;}
            var newUser = { nickname: req.body.nickname, password: hash };

            dbo.collection("users").insertOne(newUser, function(errd, ress) {
                if (errd) throw errd;
                console.log("1 user document inserted");
                db.close();
                res.send("200 OK");
            });
        });
    });
});

app.get('/membership/login/form', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(public + 'user/login.html');
});

app.post('membership/login/submit', function(req, res) {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(errdd, db) {
        if (errdd) throw errdd;
        var dbo = db.db("boaichat");
        dbo.collection("users").findOne({nickname: req.body.nickname}, function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (result) {
                bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, result.password, function(err, ress) {
                    console.log(ress);
                    res.send(ress);
                });
            }
        });
        db.close();
    });
});

// IGNORE THIS

app.post('api/v1/getSessionValid', function(req, res) {
    let token = req.body.token;
    let userInfo = token.split('_._');
    if (userInfo[0] && userInfo[1]) {

    }
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('connection');
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log("disconnection");
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it says 'Cannot post /membership/login/submit'.

Don't forget the **`/`** at the beginning of your route.

```
// Try this
app.post('/membership/login/submit', ...)

// Instead of
app.post('membership/login/submit', ...)
```